# The size of a font - larger

Tags: fontsize

this is my document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{czech}

\begin{document}

\begin{quote}
\itshape\uv{V poledne vám přijde textová zpráva z neznámého čísla, že máte večer dorazit ke staré městské továrně. Ne, to není žádná vyděračská akce, ale pozvánka na večeři. V Praze vznikla první pop-up restaurace, která se z ničeho nic objeví na neznámém místě. Organizátoři si sami vybírají hosty a jídla z přísně tajného menu jim servírují na netradičních místech.}
\end{quote}


\begin{quotation}
V poledne vám přijde textová zpráva z neznámého čísla, že máte večer dorazit ke staré městské továrně. Ne, to není žádná vyděračská akce, ale pozvánka na večeři. V Praze vznikla první pop-up restaurace, která se z ničeho nic objeví na neznámém místě. Organizátoři si sami vybírají hosty a jídla z přísně tajného menu jim servírují na netradičních místech.
\end{quotation}

\end{document}
```

I want to make the size of a font little bit larger. It is the same problem as my someone else has 1 hour ago. It writes me warnings when I use

```
\fontsize{10.62222pt}{17pt}\selectfont.: Font shape IL2/cmr/m/n in size   
 10.62222pt pt not available, substituted for 10pt.
```

Comment: Why don't you try `\documentclass[11pt]{article}`?

Comment: It has to be smaller (but larger than 10pt) and the font cant be changed.

Comment: The `czech` package has been obsolete since at least 2006; what TeX distribution are you running?

Comment: TeX Live 2011 ...

Comment: I get the following error, if I compile your file on TeX Live 2011: `! Package babel Error: You have used an old interface to call babel. You may expect compatibility problems with other packages`

Comment: So is there any solution to get the size of the font to something between 10pt and 11pt (without uni/installing any software)?

Answer (score 1):

I'll teach you a trick, but don't tell anybody.

```
\mag=1062
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\usepackage[paperheight=29.7truecm,paperwidth=21truecm,
  textwidth=345truept]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{quote}
\itshape\uv{V poledne vám přijde textová zpráva z neznámého čísla, že máte večer dorazit ke 
staré městské továrně. Ne, to není žádná vyděračská akce, ale pozvánka na večeři. V Praze 
vznikla první pop-up restaurace, která se z ničeho nic objeví na neznámém místě. 
Organizátoři si sami vybírají hosty a jídla z přísně tajného menu jim servírují na 
netradičních místech.}
\end{quote}


\begin{quotation}
V poledne vám přijde textová zpráva z neznámého čísla, že máte večer dorazit ke staré 
městské továrně. Ne, to není žádná vyděračská akce, ale pozvánka na večeři. V Praze vznikla 
první pop-up restaurace, která se z ničeho nic objeví na neznámém místě. Organizátoři si 
sami vybírají hosty a jídla z přísně tajného menu jim servírují na netradičních místech.
\end{quotation}

\end{document}
```

It's admittedly not perfect, of course, but for a simple application it can do. I'm not sure why you would need such a fussy fine tuning.

In any case, don't load `czech`, but use the

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
```

way.

Comment: It gives me hundred of errors. (TeX Live 2011, TeXnicCenter)

Comment: You probably aren't saving the document with UTF-8. Change to the encoding you're used to, but, please, update your TeX system as soon as possible.